# Why I can't access files in C

Tags: c, windows, path, character-encoding

I'm trying to access a file but I'm having problems accessing the directory.
My windows is in Portuguese so `Área de Trabalho` means `Desktop`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("C://Users//gluci//OneDrive//Área de Trabalho//Automatos//teste.txt", "w");
    fprintf(file, "abcde");
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried using `/`, `\`, `//`, `\\` but nothing seems to work. When I don't pass a specific directory the program works normally.

Comment: Probably because of the double slashes. What made you use `//` instead of `/`?

Comment: It's either double backward slashes, like `'\\'`, or single forward slashes, like `'/'`.

Comment: As for your problem, are you 100% sure that the file exists in that exact location? Have you tried using a path without spaces or international letters in it?

Comment: This was one of the attempts, I already tried with \\ and got nothing

Comment: Then call `perror("");` directly after `fopen`. What does it say?

Comment: "No such file or directory" but de "w" in the fopen function doesn't create when there is no file the directory? This is what happens when I don't specify the directory

Comment: It will create the file if the directory exists and you have write permissions in that directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pathnames can use `\` or `/` as separators in Windows API calls. Of course `\` must be encoded as `\\` in C strings, which you tried, but you should not use `//`.

The problem could be linked to the encoding used in the source file for the filename with the non ASCII letter `Á`.  Windows does not support UTF-8 encoded filenames by default, so if the editor encoded `C:/Users/gluci/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/Automatos/teste.txt` using UTF-8, this could cause problems.

You could try without the accent: `"C:/Users/gluci/OneDrive/Area de Trabalho/Automatos/teste.txt"`

You could also try the English name for the directory: `C:/Users/gluci/OneDrive/Desktop/Automatos/teste.txt"`

If none of these work, create a shortcut to the directory `Área de Trabalho` using just ASCII letters and use that in the pathname.

Also bear in mind that you might not have write access to the destination directory and the full path might be incorrect too.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you want a string like "C:\Users\gluci..." but to enter this as a string in C-like languages, you have to use "C:\\Users\\gluci\\..." where the first back slash escape the second in each pair.

Comment: Forward slashes works in Windows too

Comment: I know, but was trying to keep to flavour of the question

Comment: Even with 2 back slash the program still does not create the file